# TSQL calculate row value based on values of other rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named WORDS like this:

```
------------------------------
Symbol          ParentSymbol
------------------------------
a
ab
abc
abd
abda
abdb
b
ba
bb
bbbc
bbc
abcd
bbbbbbbbbbbbba
```

I want to update ParentSymbol column like this:

```
------------------------------
Symbol          ParentSymbol
------------------------------
a
ab              a
abc             ab
abd             ab
abda            abd
abdb            abd
b
ba              b
bb              b
bbbc            bb
bbc             bb
abcd            abc
bbbbbbbbbbbbba  bb 
------------------------------
```

The `ParentSymbol` column contains only values from Symbol Column or null if no parent found.

I am thinking of some kind of join based on partitioning by substring of Symbol, but I don't know how.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You want in `ParentSymbol`  second-row set first-row `Symbol` value?

Comment: yes, the value of ParentSymbol column is found only in Simbol column or null if there is no parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ParentSymbol is only one letter less?

```
UPDATE w
SET    ParentSymbol = left(Symbol, len(Symbol) - 1)
FROM   WORDS w
```

updated query

```
UPDATE  w
SET     ParentSymbol = ISNULL(p.ParentSymbol, '')
FROM    WORDS w
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 ParentSymbol = x.Symbol
            FROM    WORDS  x
            WHERE   x.Symbol    <> w.Symbol
            AND     w.Symbol    LIKE x.Symbol + '%'
            ORDER BY x.Symbol DESC
         ) p
```

Comment: no, the Symbol column can contain any string and string can contain any characters

Comment: bbbc has bb parent. Instead of bbbc could be bbbbbbbbbbbbbbc with parent bb

Comment: please update your question with such example and state the rules & logic for identifying the parent

Comment: Thank you! Result is as expected and is fast enough! My table has over 44000 different words and took about 2 minutes

Comment: add a index to `Symbol` column if you don't have one

Answer (score 1):

The following code first finds the closest one to the value as a substring.

```
/*
create table #words (Symbol varchar(100), ParentSymbol varchar(100));
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('a')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('ab')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('abc')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('abd')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('abda')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('abdb')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('b')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('ba')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('bb')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('bbbc')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('bbc')
insert into #words (Symbol) values ('abcd')
*/

with cte as(
select w2.Symbol  as ChildSymbol,
        max(w.Symbol) as Symbol
from #words as w
    inner join #words as w2 ON w.Symbol <> w2.Symbol and charindex(w.Symbol,w2.Symbol) = 1
group by w2.Symbol
)
select w.Symbol,
        c.Symbol as ParentSymbol
from #words as w
    left outer join cte as c ON w.Symbol = c.ChildSymbol
```

Comment: Thank you! The result is it ok but on my table that has 44000 different words took about 16 minutes to finish. Based on your solution I try to find now a way to make it faster. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `dense_rank` and `row_number` window functions.

Second Try -

```
declare @table table (Symbol varchar(10));
insert into @table values 
('a')
,('ab')
,('abc')
,('abd')
,('abda')
,('abdb')
,('b')
,('ba')
,('bb')
,('bbbc')
,('bbc')
,('abcd');

;with cte as (
    select left(symbol, 1) as FirstSymbol
    from @table
    group by left(symbol, 1)
),
cte2 as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by b.firstSymbol order by a.symbol) as RankInGroup
    from @table as a
    left join cte as b on left(a.Symbol, 1) = b.FirstSymbol
)
select a.Symbol as Symbol, b.Symbol as ParentSymbol
from cte2 as a
left join cte2 as b on a.FirstSymbol = b.FirstSymbol and a.RankInGroup = b.RankInGroup + 1;
```

First Try -

```
declare @table table (Symbol varchar(10));
insert into @table values 
('a')
,('ab')
,('abc')
,('abd')
,('abda')
,('abdb')
,('b')
,('ba')
,('bb')
,('bbbc')
,('bbc')
,('abcd');
--select * from @table;

;with cte as (
    select
        symbol,
        dense_rank() over (
            order by (
                case
                    when symbol like 'a%' then 1 when symbol like 'b%' then 2 when symbol like 'c%' then 3 when symbol like 'd%' then 4
                    when symbol like 'e%' then 5 when symbol like 'f%' then 6 when symbol like 'g%' then 7 when symbol like 'h%' then 8
                    when symbol like 'i%' then 9 when symbol like 'j%' then 10 when symbol like 'k%' then 11 when symbol like 'l%' then 12
                    when symbol like 'm%' then 13 when symbol like 'n%' then 14 when symbol like 'o%' then 15 when symbol like 'p%' then 16
                    when symbol like 'q%' then 17 when symbol like 'r%' then 18 when symbol like 's%' then 19 when symbol like 't%' then 20
                    when symbol like 'u%' then 21 when symbol like 'v%' then 22 when symbol like 'w%' then 23 when symbol like 'x%' then 24
                    when symbol like 'y%' then 25 when symbol like 'z%' then 26
            end)
        ) as GroupNumber,
        row_number() over (
            partition by (
                case
                    when symbol like 'a%' then 1 when symbol like 'b%' then 2 when symbol like 'c%' then 3 when symbol like 'd%' then 4
                    when symbol like 'e%' then 5 when symbol like 'f%' then 6 when symbol like 'g%' then 7 when symbol like 'h%' then 8
                    when symbol like 'i%' then 9 when symbol like 'j%' then 10 when symbol like 'k%' then 11 when symbol like 'l%' then 12
                    when symbol like 'm%' then 13 when symbol like 'n%' then 14 when symbol like 'o%' then 15 when symbol like 'p%' then 16
                    when symbol like 'q%' then 17 when symbol like 'r%' then 18 when symbol like 's%' then 19 when symbol like 't%' then 20
                    when symbol like 'u%' then 21 when symbol like 'v%' then 22 when symbol like 'w%' then 23 when symbol like 'x%' then 24
                    when symbol like 'y%' then 25 when symbol like 'z%' then 26
            end) order by symbol
        ) as RankInGroup
    from @table
)
select a.Symbol as Symbol, b.Symbol as ParentSymbol
from cte a
left join cte b on a.GroupNumber = b.GroupNumber and a.RankInGroup = b.RankInGroup + 1;
```

Comment: Symbol colum can contain any string and the begining character could be any character includind numbers or anything else. I am thinking of some recursive way that shoul look for Symbol element that contain substring (Symbol, Length(Simbol-1)) until it is found the first SYmbol that match. I know how to do this in a programming language but I don't know how can I do this in SQL Server

Comment: @burga_b Updated my answer.

Comment: Your result:
Simbol  ParentSimbol
100          NULL
10000  100
1000000         10000
100000001A 1000000
100000002A 100000001A
100000002C 100000002A
100000002D 100000002C
100000002E 100000002D
100000002F 100000002E
101          100000002F

Should be:
100          NULL
10000  100
1000000         10000
100000001A 1000000
100000002A 1000000
100000002C 1000000
100000002D 1000000
100000002E 1000000
100000002F 1000000
101          NULL